# Seeing discharge after ghusl

Tags: salat, women, wudu, ghusl

Today I had made ghusl because I thought my period was done. I then prayed and carried on with my day. After Maghrib I went to the bathroom and saw a brownish-reddish discharge. The colour was dark but there was traces of dried blood beside the discharge. Should I re make ghusl?